# Django - How to use a custom class in a view?

Tags: django, django-views

I've coded some classes in pure python, but now I need to use that classes in a django view.

my_custom_classes.py

```
class RetryException(Exception):
   ...
   ...

class Trade():
   def __init__(self):
       ...
       ...

   def some_other(self, id):
       ...
       ...
```

For example I need to make a call to a django model inside the "some_other(self, id)".

What is the best way of organizing this custom classes for using in a Django view?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between using a python class in a django view and using a class inside a "normal" python function.

Instantiate your class, and call its methods.

Do you have a `Trade` model? If so, would it makes sense to put that functionality in the `Trade` model class?

If you need to call something inside of your `Trade` class, what you are calling has to be in scope.  If you are querying a model you can import it in the module `Trade` is defined in, and you can access it as you expect.

```
from yourproject.yourapp.models import AModel

class Trade(object):
    def some_other(self, id):
         return AModel.objects.filter(pk=id)
```

Comment: I am confused about the convention of this... I understand that you could do this, but the classes in models.py (from what I can tell) are used in conjunction with django's database. Is there a django standard for handling custom classes? From their site: Each model is a Python class that subclasses django.db.models.Model.
Each attribute of the model represents a database field.